# Inline comments for Bash?

Tags: bash, comments

I'd like to be able to comment out a single flag in a one-line command. Bash only seems to have `from # till end-of-line` comments. I'm looking at tricks like:

```
ls -l $([ ] && -F is turned off) -a /etc
```

It's ugly, but better than nothing. Is there a better way?

The following seems to work, but I'm not sure whether it is portable:

```
ls -l `# -F is turned off` -a /etc
```

Comment: The `#comment` trick is also mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522631/bash-how-to-put-line-comment-for-a-multi-line-command

Comment: Following the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12797512/1342186) mentioned by @Juha Palomäki, there is this wonderful trick `${IFS#comment}` introduced by @pjh in the comments. No sub-shell is invoked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put a line comment for a multi-line command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522631/how-to-put-a-line-comment-for-a-multi-line-command)

Answer (score 172):

My preferred is:

[Commenting in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455988/commenting-in-bash-script#answer-1456019)

> This will have some overhead, but technically it does answer your question
>
> ```
> echo abc `#put your comment here` \
>      def `#another chance for a comment` \
>      xyz etc
> ```
>
> And for pipelines specifically, there is a cleaner solution with no overhead
>
> ```
> echo abc |        # normal comment OK here
>      tr a-z A-Z | # another normal comment OK here
>      sort |       # the pipelines are automatically continued
>      uniq         # final comment
> ```
>
> [How to put a line comment for a multi-line command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9522631/#12797512)

Comment: Note that you have to use backticks, `$(#comment)` does not work.

Comment: Some versions will consider the `)` as part of the commentary itself. Most of the challenges of bash are due to retro compatibility with older versions, and one common strategy is to use the oldest solution possible.

Comment: Note, this is not a real comment: `true && \`# comment\` && true` is a valid expression. A real comment would generate something like: `syntax error near unexpected token `&&'`

Comment: You are right @sebastianwagner, note also that it would fail in a OR short circuit or something like that, but I think it's as good as we can get without complicating things a lot. To me it's a sign that one needs a better language, but it can do great, maintaining the already built code with such 'coments' to document it.

Comment: Thanks that helped me out!

Comment: I prefer `$: echo hello, $( : 'comment, comment.' ) foo`. You can even make multiline comments with that if you need to, though personally I have *NEVER* seen a case where this was needed enough to warrant embedding it in the middle of a command.

Comment: This is awesome! : D But it breaks my syntax highlighting in vim : /

Comment: that form `# xxx` not works if the comment has a exclamation mark, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60166019/why-line-comment-tricks-for-bash-not-works-with-exclamation-mark

Comment: Neat observation made at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524367/inline-comments-for-bash/23872003?noredirect=1#comment106416104_23872003 by @william-leung, but the '!' exclamation mark only triggers a history search it it is immediately followed by a non blank char, which would be weird in english text/comment.

Comment: @Rafareino I found this issue because I use this tricks and ref some github issue / pr (!number) in the comment

Answer (score 63):

I find it easiest (and most readable) to just copy the line and comment out the original version:

```
#Old version of ls:
#ls -l $([ ] && -F is turned off) -a /etc
ls -l -a /etc
```

Comment: but then it isn't inline? i suppose its fair to say that needing to do things this unsupported by bash is cause to find another way

Answer (score 30):

`$(: ...)` is a little less ugly, but still not good.

Comment: By this syntax you are firing a sub-shell, a comment is suposed to improve redability without changing the code behavior at all, but the time to lauch/end this sub shell will make your code to be slower (to say the least), why not use only the  colon in the start of a new line?

Comment: With ${IFS#...} no sub-shell is invoked.

Comment: @Rafareino: yeah. But seriously, in 95% of applications this overhead won't matter at all. For many of the cases where it does matter, it would probably have been a good idea to use a faster language than Bash in the first place.

Comment: ... trouble is, the `$(: ...)` syntax doesn't actually seem to allow embedding comments: whereas ``echo "foo" `# comment` "bar"`` will terminate the comment at the second backtick, the supposed equivalent `echo "foo" $(: # comment) "bar"` doesn't parse anything behind the `#`.

Comment: Instead of backtick you can use single or double quotes inside the `$(: )`
- for example:
`echo "foo" $(: "# comment") "bar"` - not pretty, but meets the requirements

Answer (score 7):

Here's my solution for inline comments in between multiple piped commands.

Example uncommented code:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    cat input.txt \
    | grep something \
    | sort -r
```

Solution for a pipe comment (using a helper function):

```
    #!/bin/sh
    pipe_comment() {
        cat - 
    }
    cat input.txt \
    | pipe_comment "filter down to lines that contain the word: something" \
    | grep something \
    | pipe_comment "reverse sort what is left" \
    | sort -r
```

Or if you prefer, here's the same solution without the helper function, but it's a little messier:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    cat input.txt \
    | cat - `: filter down to lines that contain the word: something` \
    | grep something \
    | cat - `: reverse sort what is left` \
    | sort -r
```

Comment: As an aside, if you move the pipe character to the end of the previous line, you can get rid of the yucky backslash-newlines.

Comment: @tripleee yes, at the cost of copy-paste friendly line-wise editing, which is the usual reason for linewise prefixing of n-ary operators

Comment: @tripleee More importantly, when you move the `|` to the end of the line, you can just use trailing bash comments... `| # this is fine`. So that's a clear win.

Answer (score 4):

Most commands allow args to come in any order.  Just move the commented flags to the end of the line:

```
ls -l -a /etc # -F is turned off
```

Then to turn it back on, just uncomment and remove the text:

```
ls -l -a /etc -F
```

Comment: damn, I added `#` without a single whitespace after the command. thank you!

Answer (score 4):

How about storing it in a variable?

```
#extraargs=-F
ls -l $extraargs -a /etc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know a variable is empty, you could use it as a comment. Of course if it is not empty it will mess up your command.

```
ls -l ${1# -F is turned off} -a /etc
```

[§ 10.2. Parameter Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

Comment: Use `${name:=comment}` to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

For disabling a part of a command like `a && b`, I simply created an empty script `x` which is on path, so I can do things like:

```
mvn install && runProject
```

when I need to build, and

```
x mvn install && runProject
```

when not (using <kbd>Ctrl + A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + E</kbd> to move to the beginning and end).

As noted in comments, another way to do that is Bash built-in `:` instead of `x`:

```
$  : Hello world, how are you? && echo "Fine."
Fine.
```

Comment: Such a builtin already exists: `:` As in: `string; of; commands; : disabled; enabled;`

Comment: Even better :) Thanks

Comment: Both `x` and `:` are dangerous because they will obey expansion and redirection rules. So the text of the comments is potentially executed, at least in part. This can lead to all sorts of unwanted side effects.

Comment: @bitmask, sure. I think at least for `x` it is obvious that it's taking the rest as parameters, which may evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `$(...)` doesn't survive from `ps -ef`.

My scenario is that I want to have a dummy param that can be used to identify the very process. Mostly I use this method, but the method is not workable everywhere. For example, `python program.py` would be like

```
mkdir -p MyProgramTag;python MyProgramTag/../program.py
```

The `MyProgramTag` would be the tag for identifying the process started.