# bash command spanning multiple lines with several lines of comments in-between

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bash: How to Put Line Comment for a Multi-line Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522631/bash-how-to-put-line-comment-for-a-multi-line-command)

I would like to do something like this

```
sudo apt-get install \
  #a very long description
  #of the package
  #that spans multiple lines
  pkg1 \ #maybe I want an inline comment also
  #another description that
  #spans multiple lines
  pkg2
```

Note that I'm not just interested in the `apt-get` command.

Comment: have you tried putting this in a shell script and running it?

Comment: The post pointed to as a possible duplicate asks about in-line comments. I was interested in multi-line comments. But the same workaround there does work. Thanks.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

As far as I know Bash ignores everything after the '#' in a single command, and multilining won't change that. However you can probably achieve the same level of expression using bash arrays:

```
packagelist=(
  package1 # Inline Comments
  # Multiline Comments too
  package2
  # Package description goes here
  # Detailed descriptions..
)
sudo apt-get install ${packagelist[@]}
```