# Line continuation + line comment, on the same line?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a call with a pretty long list of arguments in my shell script:

```
foo-command \
    --important-argument $ONE \
    --indispensable-flag $ENABLED \
    --an-optional-toggle "will probably be commented out some day" \
    $ARGUMENTS \
    $MORE_ARGUMENTS
```

Can't I insert comments in this multiline call, can I?

For example, lets say, how can I comment out the `--an-optional-toggle` line?
How can I add an `# in sorted order` comment after `$ARGUMENTS`?

No matter what I try, the octothorp `#` symbol shadows line continuation backslash `\`, or vice versa. Any advise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but you can store the arguments in an array instead. This allows you to both comment out an individual line as well as include interspersed comments.

```
args=( --important-argument "$ONE"
       --indispensable-flag "$ENABLED"
       # --an-optional-toggle "will probably be commented out some day"
       $ARGUMENTS  # in sorted order
       $MORE_ARGUMENTS
     )
foo-command "${args[@]}"
```

Note that you will almost certainly want to make `ARGUMENTS` and `MORE_ARGUMENTS` arrays as well, so `args` would end up looking like

```
args=( --important-argument "$ONE"
       --indispensable-flag "$ENABLED"
       # --an-optional-toggle "will probably be commented out some day"
       "${ARGUMENTS[@]}"  # in sorted order
       "${MORE_ARGUMENTS[@]}"
     )
```

Comment: +1 using BASH arrays is the right way than using long multiline command line.

Comment: As a side note: this is strictly a Bash-dependent approach. Arrays don't work in older shells a.k.a "`sh`", which may be of importance for someone.

Comment: If you are concerned about portability, tag your question `sh` instead of `bash`.

Comment: It should probably be noted that using an array with `"${ARGUMENTS[@]}"` instead of a plain, unquoted `$ARGUMENTS` variable avoids unwanted pathname expansion of the value.

Answer (score 6):

Try the *backtick comment hack* [as proposed in an earlier response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522631/bash-how-to-put-line-comment-for-a-multi-line-command#12797512) to the same question.

In your case, this would be:

```
foo-command \
    --important-argument $ONE \
    --indispensable-flag $ENABLED \
    `#--an-optional-toggle "will probably be commented out some day"` \
    $ARGUMENTS \
    $MORE_ARGUMENTS
```

Comment: Take care that the commented line does not itself contain command substitutions, since they will still be expanded.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo-command $(
    # hello
    printf --important-argument $ONE # free as a bird
    printf --indispensable-flag $ENABLED
    # to comment anywhere we wish
    printf --an-optional-toggle "will probably be commented out some day"
    printf $ARGUMENTS
    printf $MORE_ARGUMENTS
)
```

It's not perfect: echoing `-n` is hard because `echo` interprets it; quotes may be disappeared when you would prefer to keep them, etc.  In fact as commenters say below, the quoted string will get mangled; maybe you can work around that, but other answers here are better if you have Bash.

Comment: If the argument to the optional comment actually contains whitespace, this will not work.

Comment: This can be improved. `printf` instead of `echo` will alleviate some problems, including `-n` (and others) interpretation. Command substitution can be inlined and get rid of an extra function definition.

Comment: You guys are right, @chepner's answer is pretty much a better version of what I did here.  All hail the bash master.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, cheer up! Your solution has an advantage of being *portable*, in the sense of compatibility with plain `sh`.

Comment: @ulidtko: Thanks.  I wouldn't wish plain `sh` on my worst enemy.  I guess it's better than `ed`.  :)

Comment: @ulidtko Portability doesn't matter if it isn't correct. However, I thought I remembered someone telling me that arrays may be added to the POSIX specification. There really isn't a portable alternative to their use in a case like this, short of a truly horrific construction involving `eval`.

Comment: (Hm, it might be ANSI-style quoting `$'...'` that I heard was under deliberation. But arrays would be useful as well.)

Comment: Note that `printf(1)` tries to expand its first argument, so using plain `printf $ARGUMENTS` is not a very good idea. `printf "%s\n" $ARGUMENTS` is better.