# Is it possible to comment inline in a multi-line newline escaped script?

Tags: bash

When I have [long multi-line piped commands in my scripts](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/90825899176bf0f345da1726f7614943eeedc379/utils/scripts/git-delete-merged#L69) I would like to comment on what each line does, but I haven't found a way of doing so.

Given this snippet:

```
git branch -r --merged \
| grep "  $remote"  \
| egrep -v "HEAD ->"  \
| util.esed -n 's/  \w*\/(.*)/\1/p' \
| egrep -v \
    "$(skipped $skip | util.esed -e 's/,/|/g' -e 's/(\w+)/^\1$/g' )" \
| paste -s
```

Is it possible to insert comments in between the lines? It seems that using the backslash to escape the newline prevents me from adding comments at the end of the line, and I can't add the comment before the backslash, as that would hide the escaping.

**Pseudo-code of what I would like the above script to look like**

It seems I was unclear (?) of what I wanted by the above section, so to have a clue on what I am looking for, it should be in the similar vein of this:

```
git branch -r --merged \ # list merged remote branches
| grep "  $remote"  \    # filter out the ones for $remote
| egrep -v "HEAD ->"  \  # remove some garbage

#strip some whitespace:
| util.esed -n 's/  \w*\/(.*)/\1/p' \     

#  remove the skipped branches:
| egrep -v \
    "$(skipped $skip | util.esed -e 's/,/|/g' -e 's/(\w+)/^\1$/g' )" \
| paste -s               # something else
```

It doesn't have to be *exactly* like this (obviously, it's not valid syntax), but something similar. If it's not possible directly, due to syntactical restrictions, perhaps it's possible to write self-modifying code that will have comments that are removed before executing it?

Comment: Possible answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12797512/5411198

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
git branch --remote | # some comment
    grep origin | # another comment
    tr a-z A-Z
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's not a general solution for commenting, but when it comes to piped commands only, which is what the question was about, it is perfect. You can see me employing it here: https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/commit/945f5b4deda7189459a0ed486fba132ac4b574a2#diff-5213268af30c91452c53ccc19056297dR77

Comment: I am glad I could help. Definitely, after a change, one can much easier comprehend what is going on with those multiple pipes.