# Comment multi-line bash statements

Tags: bash

I want to manually comment and uncomment lines in a multi-line statement, within a script file. Consider for example:

```
./configure \
  --prefix /usr/local \
  --with-option1 \
  --with-option2
```

I want to be able to do something like this (basically, ignoring the option1 switch):

```
./configure \
  --prefix /usr/local \
  #--with-option1 \
  --with-option2
```

Is there a way to do it without deleting and undoing the delete?

Comment: There's some good answers here: [How to put a line comment for a multi-line command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522631/how-to-put-a-line-comment-for-a-multi-line-command)

Comment: Technically, it's not a comment that stays in there.. but I guess, a few more key strokes with ``#`` is not too bad. Thanks.

Comment: If you comment `--with-option1` with a `#` in your multi-line command then the `bash` syntax becomes invalid.