# Continuation and comment together for bash?

Tags: bash

When I have a long line of calling a command with its arguments, is it possible to break it into several lines, and have a commend for each line?

For example, if I break `free -h` into two lines

```
free \
-h
```

how can I add a comment for each line? An attempt like this one

```
free \ # this is the command
-h  # this is the argument
```

doesn't work.

Comment: [bash-multi-line-command-with-comments-after-the-continuation-character](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19124/bash-multi-line-command-with-comments-after-the-continuation-character)

Comment: Not quite a perfect duplicate, so I won't wield my hammer but I think that basically the only way you can do this is using one of the techniques mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2524367/2088135

Comment: solution [by DigitalRoss](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1456019/4767343)

Comment: found a better one :)

Comment: I'm surprised none of those duplicates show a way to do that without forking a number of subshells. (oh, Jose's link does.)

Comment: Alas, this question was closed before I could answer.  The answer was provided in the comment section of the linked-to article, but not as a proper answer.  I'll add it here even though formatting is non-existent in the comment section.  This is on two lines.  While a little clunky it works without spawning subshells:  `who ${IFS# This is the command} \
-u  ${IFS# This is the argument}`

Comment: @Gary_W That assumes `IFS` contains only whitespace (which is generally a good assumption, but not guaranteed).

Comment: Although you could define a variable yourself to use instead of `IFS`. `comment=; who ${comment# This is the command \ ...`. I'd post that to the linked duplicate, which isn't closed.

Comment: True I should have said an alternative answer.

Comment: @Chepner that is the best method yet in my opinion. Please post that to the linked post so I can vote for it and call it a day.

Answer (score 3):

Store the arguments in an array, and document them there.

```
args=(--arg1      # First option
      --arg2 bar  # Second option with an argument
)

# Run free with the above arguments
free "${args[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

A classic trick for this is using inlined comments in backticks:

```
free `#This is the command` \
-h   `#This is the argument`
```

Comment: An expensive trick, though, since you have to spawn a subshell for each comment.