# Why does line comment tricks for bash not work with exclamation mark "!"

Tags: bash

ref [Inline comments for Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524367/inline-comments-for-bash/23872003#23872003)

We can use this tricks

```
echo abc `#put your comment here` \
     def `#another chance for a comment` \
     xyz etc
```

but these do not work if we have an exclamation mark in comment

```
echo 1 `# 2 !3`
<error>
-bash: !3: event not found
```

if we type it directly it will not be translated to an event

```
# 2 !3
<that is OK>
```

It seams that we need an other `#` symbol to workaround it.

```
echo 1 `# 2 #!3`
<that is OK>
1
```

or do we have to double the leading `#` symbol?

```
echo 1 `# # 2 !3`
<that is OK>
1
```

Comment: It's not specific to comments, you'd have the same issue in other pieces of code. You will want either to single-quote your comment, or to disable history expansion using `set +H`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape history expansion exclamation mark ! inside a double quoted string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125658/how-to-escape-history-expansion-exclamation-mark-inside-a-double-quoted-string)

Comment: @Aaron it seems to be a different issue

Comment: Yeah somewhat, because the OP of the question used a syntax that would now work but didn't in bash < 4.4. The question and various answers do discuss the history expansion that is the root of your problem though. Doesn't quoting your exclamation marks work?

Comment: @Aaron  quote not works, but I found double the leading hash can workarounds

Comment: It must be because expansion is performed twice as you're using a subshell. I'm afraid your double hash only works because you now have enough history that `!3` does refer to an history event and is expanded to its value (which is ignored since it's in a comment) rather than raise an error. You should try it just after having performed `history -c`. using `set +H` would be sure to work though

Comment: @Aaron I am sure it is not related with history length, change !3 to !3333333 still works: `echo 1 \`# # 2 !333333\``

Comment: Hmm I don't get why it works, but if it works good enough I guess? I'll see if I can understand what's happening

Comment: I've reproduced your double-hash trick and still don't understand why it works, but I've also been able to successfully use single-quotes to avoid the problem in a way I understand : both ``echo 1 `# 2 '!'3`` and ``echo 1 `# '2 !3'`` work without error in my shell (the leading hash must be left out of the comment to have a valid command though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>(The following explanation turned out to be **WRONG** though it explained everything. See the **UPDATE** as follows.)</sup>

1. `# !xxx`

   This works as expected because `!` is in the comment.
2. `echo # !xxx`

   This also works as expected because `!` is also in the comment.
3. `` echo `true # !xxx` ``

   This also works because `!` is still in the comment, though it's in the `` `...` `` context.
4. `` echo `# !xxx` ``

   Why doesn't this work?

   I guess there's a little **bug** when Bash interprets the `` `...` `` part. In `` `...` ``, Bash always assumes (wrongly) the **first** WORD is  a COMMAND name so it does not think `!` is in a comment and so history expansion is triggered. That's to say, `` echo `# !xxx` `` is just like `` echo `COMMAND !xxx` ``.
5. `` echo `# # !xxx` ``

   Why does this work?

   As explained in **#4**, the first `#` is parsed as a COMMAND so it's just like `` echo `COMMAND # !xxx` `` so now `!` is in the comment.
6. `` echo `## !xxx` ``

   This double hash does not work either.

   As explained in **#4** and **#5**, here `##` is the first WORD and it's parsed as the COMMAND name so it's also like `` echo `COMMAND !xxx` ``.

Note that, in the `` `...` `` context, the **bug** is only in the first round syntax **parser**. That's to say, even though Bash initially parses the `#` as a COMMAND name, it does not really run it as a command which is named `#`.

---

## UPDATE 2020-03-04

The above explanation turned out to be **WRONG** though it explained everything. Please see [the discussion in bug-bash mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2020-03/msg00005.html).

I'd quote Chet's explanation here for easy reference:

> ```
> > $ set -H
> > $ true `# !xxx`
> > bash: !xxx`: event not found
> ```
>
> Well, the history comment character (`#`) is not found at the start of a
> word <sup>(here `#` is part of the *word* `` `# ``)</sup>, so the rest of the line is processed for history expansion.
>
> ```
> $ true `# # !xxx`
> ```
>
> The history comment character is found at the start of a word <sup>(here the 2nd `#` itself is a *word*)</sup> and history
> expansion skips the rest of the line.
>
> Readline history expansion knows very little about shell syntax; in
> particular, **it doesn't know backquotes. It never has.**