# Bash command stopped working after adding inline comment

Tags: bash, comments, variable-assignment, syntax-highlighting, silent

The assignment of a new value generated in a subshell does work without the trailing comment:

```
newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's@TD.'"$oldnewTD"'@TD.r'"$ftd1"'@')
```

But the variable `newname` stays unchanged if a trailing comment is added:

```
newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's@TD.'"$oldnewTD"'@TD.r'"$ftd1"'@')# let us not change NonEqRead to NonEq
```

Why?

Bash version 5.0.3.

Answer (score 4):

It turned out the **space BEFORE the hash** is extremely important in `bash` — something not frequently mentioned because it apparently seems too obvious due to otherwise impaired readability. When You use the syntax highlighting, however, it is easy to leave out that whitespace without noticing it (editor-dependent problem, of course; e.g., `vim` is affected). I spent a good time trying to figure out where the error was.

```
newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's@TD.'"$oldnewTD"'@TD.r'"$ftd1"'@') # let us not change NonEqRead to NonEq
```

Without the whitespace, the whole line *silently fails* (i.e., without any error message). As far as I understand, `bash` tries to interpret the hash as a some modifier to the subshell or to the assignment operator. In any case, this seems to be connected with how the bash scripts are read word by word.

See the explanation for a related case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60238806/2010413

Comment: From https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Comments, `a word beginning with ‘#’ causes that word and all remaining characters on that line to be ignored` If you don't have a space, `#` will not start a word, but will be part of the last word returned by subshell.