# Ansible Playbook: ERROR: sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unterminated `s' command"

Tags: ansible

I have a file that has a list of my job API codes, and the status of that API but in the next line.

The `api_file`:

```yaml
"id": "3b96db40-507e-4dd8-b2fd-e0e237fb928f",
"enabled": true,
"id": "3c07b7a7-0165-4017-84c6-b7e7383105a4",
"enabled": true,
"id": "41b2ed8f-8a21-4b3b-a690-2d7f24e577f6",
"enabled": true,
"id": "42767867-0a93-4cc4-93f8-c3893fe63edf",
"enabled": true,
"id": "4278314e-71ec-4e80-ae35-1dd67ceef2bd",
"enabled": false,
"id": "45c0c8c8-d0b6-4d82-87c3-1c66ec08cf1d",
"enabled": true,
"id": "492f0775-f6b8-4cf6-b355-02260513bd5a",
"enabled": true,
.....
```

I want to move the status line to the API code line (pair the every two lines), and I used `sed 'N;s/[\n]//'` command, and the output should look like this:

```yaml
"id": "3b96db40-507e-4dd8-b2fd-e0e237fb928f","enabled": true,
"id": "3c07b7a7-0165-4017-84c6-b7e7383105a4","enabled": true,
"id": "41b2ed8f-8a21-4b3b-a690-2d7f24e577f6","enabled": true,
"id": "42767867-0a93-4cc4-93f8-c3893fe63edf","enabled": true,
"id": "4278314e-71ec-4e80-ae35-1dd67ceef2bd","enabled": false,
"id": "45c0c8c8-d0b6-4d82-87c3-1c66ec08cf1d","enabled": true,
"id": "492f0775-f6b8-4cf6-b355-02260513bd5a","enabled": true,
```

This works if I run it in shell command prompt, but when I use it in the Ansible playbook, I got an error:

The playbook:

```yaml
- name: retrieve the IDs from the integration APIs
  shell: "cat api_file | sed 's/^ *//'  > merged_api_file"
```

And the error output:

```json
TASK [retrieve the IDs from the integration APIs] *************************************************************************************************************************
  Friday 07 July 2023  16:12:23 +0000 (0:00:00.805)       0:00:04.707 *********** 
  fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/usr/bin/cat /mnt/stl-server-actions/opsgenie/disable/opsgenie-integrations-2023-07-06-22-15-46.conf | egrep \"\"id\"|\"enabled\"\" | sed 's/^ *//' | sed -e 'N;s/\n//' > /mnt/stl-server-actions/opsgenie/disable/opsgenie-integrations-id-2023-07-06-22-15-46.conf", "delta": "0:00:00.005732", "end": "2023-07-07 16:12:23.294963", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2023-07-07 16:12:23.289231", "stderr": "sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unterminated `s' command", "stderr_lines": ["sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unterminated `s' command"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

What is wrong with the `sed` command and how should I correct it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why the command within the description highly differs from the command within the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if I do not understand what you try to achieve finally and why, I understand that you ask

**How to remove every second line break?**

> *I want to move the status line to the API code line (pair the every two lines)*

An approach could be as shown in the minimal example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - shell:
      cmd: |
        cat api_file |  # print file content to STDOUT
        paste -d '' - - # merge lines of files from STDIN
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
```

which will result into the requested output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - '"id": "3b96db40-507e-4dd8-b2fd-e0e237fb928f","enabled": true,'
  - '"id": "3c07b7a7-0165-4017-84c6-b7e7383105a4","enabled": true,'
  - '"id": "41b2ed8f-8a21-4b3b-a690-2d7f24e577f6","enabled": true,'
  - '"id": "42767867-0a93-4cc4-93f8-c3893fe63edf","enabled": true,'
  - '"id": "4278314e-71ec-4e80-ae35-1dd67ceef2bd","enabled": false,'
  - '"id": "45c0c8c8-d0b6-4d82-87c3-1c66ec08cf1d","enabled": true,'
  - '"id": "492f0775-f6b8-4cf6-b355-02260513bd5a","enabled": true'
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to delete every second line from a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/219867/266568)
- [Remove newline](https://serverfault.com/a/375104/448950)

  > *`cat api_file | paste -  - | tr -d '\t'`*
- and many more ...

**Further Documentation**

Within the example are used [Ansible multiline Shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40230416/6771046), as well [Inline comments for Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23872003/6771046) to get a better understanding what the commands are for and doing. And mainly [`man paste`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/paste).

Answer (score 1):

The error message is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unterminated `s' command
```

The command you show in your question is **not** the command that's producing the error, which actually looks like:

```
/usr/bin/cat /mnt/stl-server-actions/opsgenie/disable/opsgenie-integrations-2023-07-06-22-15-46.conf |
 egrep \"\"id\"|\"enabled\"\" |
 sed 's/^ *//' |
 sed -e 'N;s/\n//' > /mnt/stl-server-actions/opsgenie/disable/opsgenie-integrations-id-2023-07-06-22-15-46.conf
```

The problem here is that the `\n` in the command line is being interpreted as a carriage return, so the actual shell script looks like:

```
/usr/bin/cat /mnt/stl-server-actions/opsgenie/disable/opsgenie-integrations-2023-07-06-22-15-46.conf | egrep ""id"|"enabled"" | sed 's/^ *//' | sed -e 'N;s/
//' > /mnt/stl-server-actions/opsgenie/disable/opsgenie-integrations-id-2023-07-06-22-15-46.conf
```

Look at the end of the first line:

```
...sed 's/^ *//' | sed -e 'N;s/
```

That embedded newline results in an unterminated `s///` command in your `sed` expression. You're going to need to rewrite your command to properly escape the `\n`.

You haven't shown us your actual playbook, so it's hard to suggest an appropriate fix.

---

But even after fixing that, you're going to have additional problems, since you're apparently trying to read from and write to the same file in your pipeline. That is, you have, effectively:

```
cat somefile | sed > somefile
```

That's not going to do anything other than truncate `somefile`.

Comment: Sorry I did eliminate some from the command, and the whole command in the playbook was like this:   shell: "cat api_file | egrep \"\"id\"|\"enabled\"\" | sed 's/^ *//' | sed 'N;s/[\n]//' . The egrep and the first sed worked as I tested the them earlier, and the results were like what I posted. It was the second sed that caused the error. I tried the suggestion from U880D below and it worked in the playbook.