# Is it possible to use comments when the line is split with backslashes?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I’d like to embed comments like this

```
ls -l \
-a \
# comment here
-h \
-t .
```

But it seems that’s not possible. Maybe some other variant does exist? Putting a comment right after the backslash or ending a comment with a backslash doesn’t help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible, for Bash tries to follow to POSIX guidelines and other standards.
Especially:

> If a `<newline>` follows the backslash, the shell shall interpret this as line continuation. The backslash and `<newline>`s shall be removed before splitting the input into tokens. Since the escaped `<newline>` is removed entirely from the input and is not replaced by any white space, it cannot serve as a token separator.
>   — *Shell Command Language*, [2.2.1 Escape Character (Backslash)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_02_01)

Thus, it is not possible because of how the shell parser works:

- A line starting with `#` is a comment, and nothing after gets evaluated (including a trailing `\`)
- A `\` that is not at the end of a line, is **not** a line skip.

In your script:

```
ls -l \
-a \
# comment here
-h \
-t .
```

The comment line is replaced with nothing (i.e. it has no token); and since the command, so far, is valid, and as a newline is met (`… -a ↵`), the shell runs the `ls -l -a` command, then the `-h -t .` command (and does not find a `-h` binary in your `$PATH`, so it stops right there.)

Comment: In your last paragraph, the newline that was met is at the end of the comment instead of after "-a \" I think.

Comment: @spkersten That is true, I have not been clear enough (I used a space character to represent a newline, but I should have used ↵ instead.) Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

The posts above do not have a direct solution. However, there is a direct solution that's actually mentioned in even older posts: [How to put a line comment for a multi-line command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522631/how-to-put-a-line-comment-for-a-multi-line-command) and [Commenting in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455988/commenting-in-a-bash-script).

The solution I like best is:

```
ls -l `# long format` \
-a `# all files` \
-h `# human readable` \
-t `# time sort`
```

You will need both the accent grave (`) quotation and the octothorpe (#) to indicate the comment. Use them before the backslash.

Comment: problem is this creates and executes a subshell for each comment

Comment: Very surprising... :)

Answer (score 10):

You can do something like this with an array, which doesn't require continuation characters:

```
ls_cmd=(
  ls
  -l  # long form
  -a  # show hidden files
  -h  # human-readable sizes
  -t  # sort by time
  .
)

"${ls_cmd[@]}" # run the command from the array
```

...but for the general case, the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly, buy you *can* put such comments in an array assignment. (This also allows you to split the arguments across multiple lines without using line continuation.)

```
cmd_options=(
  -l
  -a
   # comment here
  -h
  -t .
)
ls "${cmd_options[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

In that situation I usually go with something like

```
ls -l  -a  -h  -t .  
#  |   |   |   time sort
#  |   |   human readable
#  |   all files
#  long format
```

or I use the long form of the argument when they exist e.g. `--human-readable` rather than `-h`.

Comment: Now imagine that your actual command line consists of multiple parameters with long names each taking a string, so the whole command takes several lines.

Comment: @tijagi In such case I would assign the parameters by groups to variables with meaningful names as is often done in Makefile for instance. You can then interleave variable assignments with comments.

Answer (score 2):

...and it can be done after pipes:

```
echo "Hello beautiful" | \
# Display match only:
grep -o beautiful
```

But, otherwise... no.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this directly, because the comment removal is done before than the back-slash line concatenation, so this does not work

```
# commenting \
seveal lines
```

The obvious solution is to use `#` on every line:

```
# commenting
# seveal lines
```

If you want to be creative you can use a dirty trick:

```
: 'This is almost
a multiline comment'
```

Not actually a comment, but it does nothing, other than changing the exit code to 0.

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible. Because the backslash is a line continuator and the comment a single character which makes everything on its right ignored until end of line:

```
ls \
# -l \
-h
```

the `-l` will get ignored, the `ls` command executed and the `-h` considered as a new command.

Because in C-like languages you have comments with boundaries: `/* */` it's possible to place those between token in expression that uses line continuation.