# FFMPEG Error: Command not found - -c:v libx264

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I have a https input that I want to crop the top (control) and side (chat bar).

I am using the `-vf "crop=1600:980:0:1080"` and this works fine.

When I want to scale my cropped input by using
`-vf "crop=1600:980:0:180,scale=1920:1080"`

I get an Error: `Command not found - -c:v libx264`

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong here.

Here is the ffmpeg part of the script:

```
ffmpeg \
  -hide_banner -loglevel error \
  -nostdin \
  -s ${CAPTURE_SCREEN_RESOLUTION} \
  -r ${VIDEO_FRAMERATE} \
  -draw_mouse 0 \
  -f x11grab \
    -i ${DISPLAY} \
  -f pulse \
    -ac 2 \
    -i default \
    -vf "crop=1600:980:0:1080,scale=1920:1080" \
  -c:v libx264 \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -profile:v main \
    -preset slow \
    -x264opts "nal-hrd=cbr:no-scenecut" \
    -minrate ${VIDEO_BITRATE} \
    -maxrate ${VIDEO_BITRATE} \
    -g ${VIDEO_GOP} \
  -c:a aac \
    -b:a ${AUDIO_BITRATE} \
    -ac ${AUDIO_CHANNELS} \
    -ar ${AUDIO_SAMPLERATE} \
  -f flv ${RTMP_URL}
```

I have also tried to `-vf "crop=1600:980:0:1080;scale=1920:1080"`

Comment: Make sure your real file doesn't have whitespace after the backslash on the line before `-c:v libx264` -- such whitespace would negate the backslash's use. Even better, collect all your arguments into an array and then you don't need backslashes by the linebreaks at all.

Comment: That usually happens when the shell thinks the line is over.  So it interprets the `-c:v libx264` line as a new command.  Are you sure your line endings are not Windows (CRLF), no `\\` missing, all variables are set, tabs instead of spaces, ...?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27196266/14122 is an example of the array practice.

Comment: (and yes, invisible whitespace characters like CRs/carriage returns/DOS newlines can consume a backslash too, as Nic3500 suggests, and thereby prevent it from working as a line continuation).

Comment: Anyhow -- we can't reproduce the problem with the code from the question; make sure that copying-and-pasting from the question into a new file still causes the same problem.

Comment: thank you. yes it was the whitespace after either -i default \ or -c:v libx264 \
If i wanted to use the -tune zerolatency Can i use this after my preset line?