# Comment in a bash loop argument list

Tags: bash, loops, syntax, comments, indentation

I want to comment parts of a bash for loop argument list. I would like to write something like this, but I can't break the loop across multiple lines. Using `\` doesn't seem to work either.

```
for i in
  arg1 arg2     # Handle library
  other1 other2 # Handle binary
  win1 win2     # Special windows things
do .... done;
```

Comment: You should be able to use the \ to escape a linefeed.  Just make sure there are no trailing spaces after it, otherwise, you are escaping a space.  However, you will not be able to comment out arguments like you can with codeforester's solution.

Comment: @jason: doesn't work inside comments, I'm afraid

Comment: @codeforester , I rolled back your edit to the question title, it didn't line up with the actual content of the question, or the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store your values in an array and then loop through them.  The array initialization can be interspersed with comments unlike line continuation.

```
values=(
    arg1 arg2     # handle library
    other1 other2 # handle binary
    win1 win2     # Special windows things
)
for i in "${values[@]}"; do
    ...
done
```

Another, albeit less efficient, way of doing this is to use command substitution.  This approach is prone to [word splitting and globbing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108963/201820) issues.

```
for i in $(
        echo arg1 arg2     # handle library
        echo other1 other2 # handle binary
        echo win1 win2     # Special windows things
); do
  ...
done
```

---

Related:

- [Commenting in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1455988/6862601)
- [How to put a line comment in a multi-line command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9522631/6862601)
- [The Open Group Base Specifications - Token Recognition in Shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_03)

Answer (score 1):

In the code beneath I do not use `handlethings+=`, it will be too easy to forget a space.

```
handlethings="arg1 arg2"                     # Handle library
handlethings="${handlethings} other1 other2" # Handle binary
handlethings="${handlethings} win1 win2"     # Special windows things

for i in ${handlethings}; do
   echo "i=$i"
done
```

Comment: This has word splitting and globbing issues, just like the second solution in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50495101/6862601).