# Why can you not have comments in multi-line commands in sh?

Tags: bash, parsing, sh, comments, interpreter

I've looked at these posts:

- [How to put a line comment for a multi-line command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522631/how-to-put-a-line-comment-for-a-multi-line-command)
- [Commenting in a Bash script inside a multiline command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455988/commenting-in-a-bash-script-inside-a-multiline-command)

but it doesn't answer conceptually why not.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo \
# comment
-n hello
```

on [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) yields:

> -n hello
> ^-- SC2215 (warning): This flag is used as a command name. Bad line break or missing [ .. ]?

Reason I thought it would be okay:

- I had learned comments are ignored by programs (and so it should make no difference)

For example, a `C` program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  printf("hello%d\n",
         // my comment
         3);
}
```

Why is this fundamentally different in `bash` and `sh`?

How is it being interpreted that causes this (with comments not being completely ignored by the interpreter)?

My idea:

- the shell simply ignores lines with comments while parsing, but expects a continuation line after the backslash and for some reason (**why?**) breaks if a comment (which should be ignored) is there instead of looking at the next (uncommented) line
- C compiler never even sees comments because they are gone by compilation stage

Comment: A comment starts with a `#` character and extends to the end of the line. Provided that you have neither a `$` nor a `;` in your comment, you could use the no-op command `:` which simply ignores all arguments, and use this as a poor man's comment. Example: `echo x; : this is a comment; echo y`

Comment: As an explanation: From my understanding, The commented area starts at the `#` end ends right before the _newline_ character. Therefore, a `# ....` still leaves the final newline after the comment is removed. In your example, this makes `-n hello` strart in a new line. In C++ however, the `//`  comment seems to extend up to **including** the newline character.

Comment: it's not about why or why not. it's more about choices/decisions people made at some time. you can write your own shell to support it. and if you have enough power you can make new standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For POSIX shell, this behaviour is defined [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10) in chapter *2.3 Token Recognition*:

> If the current character is a '#', it and all subsequent characters up to, **but excluding**, the next *newline* shall be discarded as a comment. The *newline* that ends the line is not considered part of the comment.

*bash* simply took over this convention to make it easier to port scripts from sh to bash. From what I see, zsh is doing the same, and most likely ksh too.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So the best solution is to have comments as `: … \\` then? I wonder if you could also have the `\\` in there after a `#`.

Comment: @user129393192:Let's put it like this: The shell does not provide for comments **inside** a command (like `/* .... */` construct of C. This in not related to whether the command is on a line of its own, or stretches several line. In your concrete `echo` example, you could write the comment as `${CommenT:+this is a comment}`. As long as you ensure that you don't have a variable named `CommenT`, the shell will expand this to an empty string (due to the `:+`) and the `echo` will display only _hello_. However, I would consider this a hack. Better place your comment into a line, where it's OK.

Comment: @user12939192 : With other words: If you want to hack  the design philosophy of a programming language, you have to think of a suitable solution on a case by case base. The idea of using a dummy variable `CommenT` will work often, but is ugly. In other situations, you could use the no-op command `: .... ` to achieve a similar effect. But fighting the way a programming language is designed to be used, will in the end give you headache and doesn't make your code easier to maintain.